# AndroidX DataBinding API doesnt work

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I want to inflate my view with the DataBindingUtil like in the docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate( inflater, R.layout.fragent_report_details, container, false)
```

But i get this error:

[image]

I don't find any solution on the internet.

Comment: It should be DataBindingUtil.setContentView()

Comment: Try `DataBindingUtil<FragentReportDetailsBinding>.inflate()`, given the name of the layout that you have in your question. Or, instead of using `DataBindingUtil`, use `FragentReportDetailsBinding` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

val binding **: FragentReportDetailsBinding** = DataBindingUtil.inflate( inflater, R.layout.fragent_report_details, container, false)

instead of

val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate( inflater, R.layout.fragent_report_details, container, false)

Comment: But where is my FragmrntReportDetailsBinding class?

Comment: Android Databinding library generates it when you create fragment_report_details.xml file.

Comment: I get "Unresolved reference: FragmentReportDetailsBinding"

Comment: Clean and build the app again. You'll be able to import it

Comment: there is a type xml name is fragent_report_details. So Use exactly FragentReportDetails. Do not make any specll changes

Comment: This is a new issue. Better create a new question. We can discuss over there.

Comment: I've created a new issue. Can you help me there?